# Using dplyr to get counts

Tags: r, statistics, dplyr

I want to be able to get the counts, standard deviation and mean of certain variables after grouping them. I am able to get the mean and std, but getting the counts is giving me an error. This is the following code I have:

```
NYC_Trees %>%
    group_by(Condition) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(mean = round(mean(Compensatory.Value), 2),
                     sd   = round(sd(Compensatory.Value), 2), 
                     count(NYC_Trees,Condition, wt = Compensatory.Value))
```

I get the error: cannot handle.

I want the output such as:

```
Condition    Native     N     Mean    Std
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looking at the documentation for `count`, it looks like you should be piping the result of `summarise` into `count`, not calling it within `summarise`.  Even if you do call it w/in `summarise`, you would also have to assign the result to something, your code does not do that.

Comment: Shouldnt you use `n()` instead of `count()`

Comment: What do the `N` and `Native` stand for? Does `N` stand for the number of observations in each group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count(NYC_Trees,Condition, wt = Compensatory.Value)` should be the same as `NYC_Trees %>% group_by(Condition) %>% summarise(n = sum(Compensatory.Value)`. This clearly returns a vector and therefore the `summarise` function cannot handle it.

So you could just have the line `n = sum(Compensatory.Value)` inside the `summarise`:

```
NYC_Trees %>%
    group_by(Condition) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(mean = round(mean(Compensatory.Value), 2),
                     sd   = round(sd(Compensatory.Value), 2), 
                     n = sum(Compensatory.Value))
```

Is that what you are trying to do? If you just want the number of values in each group, you can use `n = n()` instead:

```
NYC_Trees %>%
    group_by(Condition) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(mean = round(mean(Compensatory.Value), 2),
                     sd   = round(sd(Compensatory.Value), 2), 
                     n = n())
```

Comment: Yup, that makes perfect sense. Thank you for clearing it :)

Comment: Why the `::` notation for `summarise` but not `group_by` or `n`? Does it have a naming conflict with some other common package's `summarise`? Just curious.

Comment: @alistaire: I copied this from the OP, so you probably should ask there. I would usually either consistently use the `::` notation or assume the package is loaded in the namespace. I never had a naming conflict with `summarise`, but obviously I only use a limited number of packages.